# Data type change in Python: When removing rows using drop the data type changes

Tags: python, pandas

I tried removing a row using year value.Once the row is removed the "year" column name changes to "index" and the values in the column changes to decimal point. Example: 2019 changes to 2019.0 and the column name changes from "Year" to "index". Why this change is happening and what can be done to rectify it? The code I used is given below.

```
data = df.set_index("Year")
data=data.drop("2018", axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, try using
`data = df[df.Year != 2018]`
this will drop the rows with respect to condition Year != 2018